# Highcharts drilldown from a series

Tags: highcharts, series, multiple-columns, drilldown

I have a chart that displays series data by year.
eg 1011, 1112, 1213, 1415, and shows an actual and target for each year.

If the user clicks on a column, the chart drills down into that dataset, however I'd like to be able to show Actual and Target next to each other, rather than a single column...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MuydK/

Any help appreciated, am stumped on this as tried several methods. 
I believe I understand how to set up the data into a series set rather than just a dataset, but don't know what changes I need to make to SetChart etc...

Also the Series titles disappear once I've drilled in and out once, any ideas...?

Many Thanks for you help.

```
        var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories1 = ['1011', '1112', '1213', '1415'],
        name1 = 'Actual',

        data1 = [ ...
```

Comment: however I'd like to be able to show Actual and Target next to each other? what do you mean by actual and target?

Comment: If you see jsfiddle link, you will a bar chart that contains 4 sets of actual / targets (there are simply totals), the sets are for four years, 1011, 1112, 1213 and 1415. When I click a column say for 1011 actual I see a datasets for just that column showing actuals, I want to be able to drill in and show both actuals and targets sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated your code with simple data, I think this is what you want,This is just a demo you can update code according to you.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/7xEhW/)

Here is code:

```
$(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories1 = ['1011', '1112', '1213', '1415'],
            name1 = 'Actual',

            data1 = [
{
     y: 1674,
     color: colors[0],
     drilldown: {
         name: '1011 Actual',
         categories: ['BS', 'B', 'IT', 'C'],
         data: [3, 32, 54, 50],

         color: colors[0],

         name1: '1011 Target',
         data1: [0, 31, 50, 60],
         color1:colors[1]
     }
 }
];            var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories2 = ['1011', '1112', '1213', '1415'],
            name2 = 'Target',

            data2 = [  
{
     y: 1633,
     color: colors[1],
     drilldown: {
          name: '1011 Actual',
         categories: ['BS', 'B', 'IT', 'C'],
         data: [3, 32, 54, 50],

         color: colors[0],

         name1: '1011 Target',
         data1: [0, 31, 50, 60],
         color1:colors[1]
     }
 }
];            function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
                console.log(name, categories, data, color);
                chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
                while (chart.series.length > 0) {
                    chart.series[0].remove(true);
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    chart.addSeries({
                        name: name[i],
                        data: data[i],
                        color: color[i]
                    });

                }
            }
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'con1',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Learner Responsive 16-18'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Click the columns to view breakdown by department. Click again to view by Academic Year.'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: categories1
                    , labels: {rotation:-90, align:'right'}
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Learner Responsive 16-18'
                    }
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                    if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                        setChart([drilldown.name,drilldown.name1], drilldown.categories, [drilldown.data, drilldown.data1], [drilldown.color,drilldown.color1]);
                                    } else { // restore
                                        setChart(name, categories1, [data1, data2], 'white');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: colors[0],
                            style: {
                                fontWeight: 'bold'
                            },
                            formatter: function () {
                                return this.y; // +'%';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        var point = this.point,
                        series = point.series,
                        s = 'Learner Responsive 16-18' + '<br/>' + this.x + ' ' + series.name + ' is <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';
                        if (point.drilldown) {
                            s += 'Click to view <b>' + point.category + ' ' + series.name + ' </b>' + ' by department';
                        } else {
                            s += 'Click to return to view by academic year.';
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: name1,
                    data: data1,
                    color: colors[0]
                },{
                    name: name2,
                    data: data2,
                    color: colors[1]
                }],

                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
                function (chart) {
                console.log(chart);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sir you are a star, and have got onto my select christmas card list.

Comment: Hi, I need help with highchart. I have a drilldown chart that gets data via ajax. I am having challenge with formatting the x-axis. The main column should have a label like this: 9Nov, 10Nov, 11Nov and the drilldown label should have 00.00, 00.30, 1.00,1.30..... I have been having difficulty in doing the drilldown part. I am able to do the first part. I formatted it as follows: xAxis:[ {
            type: 'datetime',
           dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
      month: '%e. %b',
      year: '%b',
      hour: '%H:%M'
     
                }  
        }] ,

Comment: The part that loads the data is as follows: series: [{
            name: 'Day Values',
            colorByPoint: false,
   pointStart: useDate,
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
   }],
        drilldown: {
    series: drilldownSeries,

        }