# Creating a drilldown chart with Highcharts that contain double(multiple) columns for each column (see example for better explanation)

Tags: c#, jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

First question here!

I'm trying to create a chart (with drill down) in High Charts that should look like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/34r8cjm5urqgmh1/year.png

When you click on a year column it should drill down to the following (month view)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cji7a534wmwt2u/month.png

One of my problems is that each column in the drill down should, how to put it, have two (multiple) columns. For example, the month view (the drill down) should have 2 columns per month (current & previous month).

I just have no clue about how to design this chart in regards to series data etc etc.

Have looked thru just about every relevant High Charts example I have been able to dig up on the net.

Regards

Joakim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this answer
[Highcharts drilldown from a series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364455/highcharts-drilldown-from-a-series)

which is just a modification of the stock drilldown demo
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I now have a working solution!